# How to validate the email field of UserCreationForm using the built-in EmailValidator in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Right now, if I enter invalid data into my UserCreationForm and submit it, the page reloads but doesn't show any error. I would like the EmailValidator validator in Django to show the error. I have tried adding the validators attribute to the email field, but it didn't do anything.

Here are my views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import CustomUserCreationForm

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            context = {
                'user': request.user,
            }
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'), context)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('register'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Project 3: TODO")

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context)

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
```

And here are my models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.validators import EmailValidator

# Create your models here.

# Customer class.
class CustomUser(User):
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

# Create user registration form class.
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150, help_text='Required.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150, help_text='Required.')
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=150, help_text='Required.', validators=[EmailValidator], error_messages={'invalid': 'This does not look like an email address.'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
    # TODO: show an error message when email is incorrectly formatted.
    # TODO: make email field unique and show an error message when it was already used.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use built in [EmailField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) of Django in **CustomUserCreationForm**

`email = forms.EmailField(...)`

[See this too (validation of email) (form.clean)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.clean), read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for showing errors of individual form fields